# What is a Grothendieck class?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I am reading a paper and I found this: "... given a Grothendieck class $\varepsilon$ on a category $C$..."

What is a Grothendieck class on a category? Is it the same of a Grothendieck universe? How is it related to the class of objects and morphisms of $C$?

Comment: I suspect that it is connected rather to the [*Grothendieck group*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+group), but I'm not sure without more context - can you link to the paper?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I cannot link because the paper is not published yet, what I can say is that it talks about so called "imaginary morphisms". They are defined as equivalence classes of spans, where the left arrow of the span is in the Grothendieck class of the category

Comment: I think without further context this question is probably unanswerable - there are lots of things you could put on a category, and many of them could reasonably be named after Grothendieck. As to imaginary morphisms, they appear in [two papers of Bourn and Janelidze](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022404909000358/1-s2.0-S0022404909000358-main.pdf?_tid=b3aceb1a-aa75-11e6-acd7-00000aacb361&acdnat=1479133498_3a8a11fed2d5d21dd07916f18c7c5f5b) in an algebraic context, which makes me suspect that we are indeed closer to Grothendieck groups (or topologies) than universes. (cont'd)

Comment: One reasonable option is to email the author and ask - besides them answering your quesiton, if the paper itself doesn't contain a definition of this term (or at least a reference to a text in which it is defined) that's something the author might want to fix before publication. (Note that this is a completely understandable omission, in particular of which I have been guilty. And I was happy to get an email informing me that I'd left out a definition!) **Note, however**, that if you take this approach you should quadruple-check that the paper doesn't in fact define the term . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber I will surely follow your advice. But for now, I seem to have found something which confirms your conjectures. Going on reading the article, I found: "...assume for now that $\varepsilon$ is the regular epimorphism topology..."